# Share volumes between separate docker compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to allow [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) to proxy between multiple containers while also accessing the static files from those containers.

To share volumes between containers created using docker compose, the following works correctly:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: webtest
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static-files:/static/teststaticfiles

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.8-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static-files:/static/teststaticfiles
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static-files:
```

However what I actually require is for the nginx compose file to be in a separate file and also in a completely different folder. In other words, the `docker compose up` commands would be run separately. I have tried the following:

First compose file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: webtest
    command: ./start.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static-files:/static/teststaticfiles
    networks:
      - directorylocation-nginx_mynetwork

volumes:
  static-files:

networks:
  directorylocation-nginx_mynetwork:
    external: true
```

Second compose file (ie: nginx):

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15.8-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static-files:/static/teststaticfiles
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes:
  static-files:

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

The above two files work correctly in the sense that the site can be viewed. The problem is that the static files are not available in the nginx container. The site therefore displays without any images etc.

One work around which works correctly [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50448471) is to change the nginx container static files volume to instead be as follows:

```
- /var/lib/docker/volumes/directory_static-files/_data:/static/teststaticfiles
```

The above works correctly, but it seems 'hacky' and brittle. Is there another way to share volumes between containers which are housed in different compose files without needing to map the `/var/lib/docker/volumes` directory.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

By separating the 2 `docker-compose.yml` files as you did in your question, 2 different volumes are actually created; that's the reason you don't see data from `web` service inside volume of `nginx` service, because there are just 2 different volumes.

Example : let's say you have the following structure :

```
example/
    |- web/
        |- docker-compose.yml # your first docker compose file
    |- nginx/
        |- docker-compose.yml # your second docker compose file
```

Running `docker-compose up` from `web` folder (or `docker-compose -f web/docker-compose.yml up` from `example` directory) will actually create a volume named **`web_static-files`** (name of the volume defined in `docker-compose.yml` file, prefixed by the folder where this file is located).

So, running `docker-compose up` from `nginx` folder will actually create **`nginx_static-files`** instead of re-using `web_static-files` as you want.

You can use the volume created by `web/docker-compose.yml` by specifying in the 2nd docker compose file (`nginx/docker-compose.yml`) that this is an external volume, and its name :

```
volumes:
  static-files:
    external:
      name: web_static-files
```

Note that if you don't want the volume (and all resources) to be prefixed by the folder name (default), but by something else, you can add `-p` option to `docker-compose` command :

```
docker-compose \
    -f web/docker-compose.yml \
    -p abcd \
    up
```

This command will now create a volume named `abcd_static-files` (that you can use in the 2nd docker compose file).

You can also define the volumes creation on its own `docker-compose` file (like `volumes/docker-compose.yml`) :

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  static-files:
```

And reference this volume as external, with name `volumes_static-files`, in web and nginx `docker-compose.yml` files :

```
volumes:
  volumes_static-files:
    external: true
```

Unfortunately, you cannot set the volume name in docker compose, it will be automatically prefixed. If this is really a problem, you can also create the volume manually (`docker volume create static-files`) before running any `docker-compose up` command (I do not recommand this solution though because it adds a manual step that can be forgotten if you reproduce your deployment on another environment).

Comment: Great answer. However, apparently, docker-compose can now set a volume name without a prefix, per: stackoverflow.com/a/59066462/1883050 (not sure what version of compose is needed for the `volume name property`, but apparently the `networks name property` only works for v3.5 and up).