# Copy data from docker-compose auto-created volume to new external volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

When you use a volume in `docker-compose`, `docker` will create a volume with the volume name appended to the directory name: `[directory containing yml]_[volume name]`

`/var/containers/my-important-server-v0.23/docker-compose.yml`

```yml
volumes:
    server-db:
    # Volume name: my-important-server-v0.23_server-db
```

Now when you move and rename the directory containing `docker-compose.yml` for reasons, it will create a new volume with the new directory prepended to the volume name.

In order to prevent this, and allow multiple compose files to use the same volume, we should have created a volume manually:

`docker volume create server-db`

```yml
volumes:
    server-db:
        external: true
```

How can we transfer the files from `my-important-server-v0.23_server-db` to `server-db`?

---

This is what I tried and seemed to make sense, but it doesn't work as expected.

```sh
docker volume create server-db
OLD=$(docker volume inspect my-important-server-v0.23_server-db | jq -r .[0].Mountpoint)
NEW=$(docker volume inspect server-db | jq -r .[0].Mountpoint)
sudo rsync -va $OLD/ $NEW/
```

Now here is the problem. The directory containing MariaDB files have different sizes. Apparently you can't simply copy the files like that.

Comment: I think your problem is answered in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051130/share-volumes-between-separate-docker-compose-files/54052250

Comment: You can also set the environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` which will override the `[directory containing yml]` part of the generated names.  It'd be more reliable to launch a container mounting both directories to do the copy.  If there are sparse files involved it's natural and not harmful for the new directory to be larger than the old one.

Comment: fwiw imho you should [use the appropriate tools to backup the database volumes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-backup-and-restore-with-mariabackup/).

Comment: @DavidMaze you were right. I did an experimental copy and run and inspect the database. The contents match, even if the size on disk varies.

Comment: @masseyb you are absolutely right. Always have a proper backup if the data is of anything resembling importance. On a lower level though, a copy of the data(files) containing the data(base) should yield the same data(base), and sometimes it's fun to take a shortcut/gamble when you're kind of sure after simulating the logic a couple of times in your head.